# Yeoman mobile with twitter bootstrap: glyphicons are missing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, compass-sass, yeoman

I've built application using `yo mobile` with twitter bootstrap support. However I can't use glyphicons as there is no `/styles/vendor/fonts` folder created (I know that glyphicons are supposed to be inside `/styles/vendor/fonts` because I can see in chrome network tab that browser unsuccessfully requests `http://localhost:3333/styles/vendor/fonts/glyphiconshalflings-regular.woff`).

Actually glyphicons are kept inside `/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts` folder. I can just copy-paste these fonts into `/styles/vendor/fonts` and it would work. But yeoman is supposed to save me from doing extra copy-paste, wright?

So the question is: is there any way to modify my config to make glyphicons appear inside `/styles/vendor/fonts` folder?

```js
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            /*fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',*/
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false
        },
        dist: {},
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add grunt-contrib-copy task to automate procedure of copying styles

I think, it will be better to add separate task for this:

```
grunt.registerTask('install', ['copy']);
```

In this task you can simply copy font styles from bower_components/bootstrap folder into /styles/vendor/fonts

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing exactly that.